# Variables that should be defined are giving me NameErrors, how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to append values to data to dump into a json file, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\techn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\techn\scrapy\KYCSpider\KYCSpider\spiders\kycspider.py", line 92, in parse
    data['Government Members'].append({
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

This problem occurred earlier with another variable, where it would not say it's defined, despite being defined outside of the function. I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here.

```
class KYCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kycspider'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.vlada.si/en/about_the_government/members_of_government/'
        ]
    allowed_domains = ['www.vlada.si']
    maxdepth = 1
    isNewDoc = False
    oldData = ''
    newFile = ''
    data = {}
    data['Government Members'] = []

    def spider_opened(self):
        print("OPENED SPIDER")
        global newFile, oldData, isNewDoc
        #If data.json exists, copy its data into a string and trunctuate it
        try:
            oldFile = open('data.json', 'r')
            oldData = oldFile.read()
            isNewDoc = False
        #If data.json file doesn't exist, tell spider that this is a new doc
        except FileNotFoundError:
            isNewDoc = True
        newFile = open('data.json', 'w')
        newFile.write("[")


    def parse(self, response):
        global data, isNewDoc
        #code that assigns values to from_name, from_designation, etc.

        data['Government Members'].append({
                    'name': from_name, 
                    'designation': from_designation,
                    'dob': dob,
                    'address': address,
                    'email': email,
                    'phone': phone,
                    'website': website,
                    'sourceURL': sourceURL,
                    'operation': operation
            })
```

I expect data to have any scraped information appended to it, so I can dump it into a JSON file when it's done crawling.

Comment: This error is due to poor programming. Before asking questions please learn how to use classes, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not `global`, its just class wide so its in `self`. I.e. use `self.data` wherever you use `data` in that method.
**Example:**

```
# remove the global statment
self.data['Government Members'].append(...)
```

Though you should use a constructor instead of just defining variables out in the open such as:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = {'Government Members': []}
def parse(self):
    print(self.data)
```

Comment: ahh thank you, I'm used to java so this is new to me.

Comment: You can look into [python classes for java users](http://python4java.necaiseweb.org/OOP/DefiningClasses), it may help you understand how it works. Only thing that article doesn't cover is private, which in python you can make "private" variables by leading them with a double underscore such as `self.__data = 2`. Private is in quotes because if you want to can still read it through special means (just like java isn't truly private).